# Laravel Angular filtering data with categories doesn't work

Tags: angular, laravel

i am working on ecommerce project with laravel and angular, i have products and brands for this products, in the function the i get the products with in laravel, i used nullable parameter like this

```
public function index($brand = null)
{
    if ($brand) {
        $products = Product::where('brand_id', '=', $brand)->get();

        return response()->json($products);
    } else {
        $products = Product::get();

        return response()->json($products);
    }
}
```

and this the api URL in laravel

```
Route::get('/products/{brand?}', 'App\Http\Controllers\ApiProductController@index');
```

in angular i need when the user join the products page i display all the products to him and there is links above the products with onclick events on them to choose specific brands

the angular html code

```
<ul class="d-flex list-unstyled justify-content-around w-50 mx-auto mt-5">
    <li (click)="onChange(null)">All</li>
    <li *ngFor="let brand of brands" (click)="onChange(brand.id)">{{ brand.name }}</li>
</ul>
```

the angular ts code

```
onChange(brand: any) {
    this.favBrand = brand;
    this._ProductsService.getProducts(this.favBrand).subscribe(data => {
      this.shuffle(data);
      this.products = data;

      this.page = 0;
      this.totalItems = this.products.length;
    });
}

constructor(public _HttpClient: HttpClient, public _BrandsService: BrandsService, public 
_ProductsService: ProductsService, public _Router: Router) {
    _ProductsService.getProducts(this.favBrand).subscribe(data => {
      this.shuffle(data);
      this.products = data;
      console.log(data);

      this.page = 0;
      this.totalItems = this.products.length;
    });

    _BrandsService.getBrands().subscribe((data) => {
      this.brands = data;
    }, (err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });
  }
```

the angular products service code

```
  getProducts(brand?: any): Observable<any> {
    return this._HttpClient.get(`http://localhost/mobitech/public/api/products/${brand}`);
  }
```

when i load the page without entering any parameters for the brand the products doesn't load and when i click on specific brand the products loads well, why did the all products doesn't show

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have a default brand which gets the data from the API when you reload and whenever the user change the brands, you already have that functionality working.

You can add here or may be the TS file.

```
getProducts(brand: any = 'defaultBrand'): Observable<any> {
    return this._HttpClient.get(`http://localhost/mobitech/public/api/products/${brand}`);
  }
```

If you don't want to show default brand list just show a message to the user to interact with the dropDown or form you have.